# Setting value of class variable from String Request Volley in Android

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I have a function named isUserExist.This func checks whether user exist on database with this email address.

In stringrequest i set the isUserExist variable "true".End of the func,func returns isUserExist.

Problem is it always returns false even if i set it true in the string request.it sets it true in the if statement.

In the class declaration of it like:

```
boolean isUserExist;
```

And the function is:

```
private boolean isUserExist()
{

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            AppConfig.URL_USER_EXIST, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
                if (error) {
                    // setting isUserExist = true
                    isUserExist = true;
                    //Log.w("debug1",String.valueOf(isUserExist);) 
                    //returns true;

                } else {

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting params to register url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("email", mail);

            return params;
        }

    };
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq);
    //Log.w("debug2",String.valueOf(isuserExist));
    //returns false
    return isUserExist;
}
```

What did i try so far :

I have searched and find these ideas.
1)to make it `static`
2)Declaring `boolean result[] = new boolean[1];` and end of the function return result[0] which i have assaign it true in String Request.
3)Declaring isUserExist as Local variable.boolean isUserExist = false; in the beggining of the func.
4)In the firs decleration assaign it like :`boolean isUserExist = false` instead of `boolean isUserExist;`

But none of them works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was working with threads.Volley thread sets the isUserExist true after function returns.

Answer (score 0):

The better apporach is to debug your code to check if your call back method is setting your boolean variable. Set two break points; First in your outer method, Second in your call back method to see the values of  all involved variables.

Comment: i actually did this.Edited the question.